# Color terminal output in Perl

Tags: perl, terminal, ncurses

I'd like to print some output to the terminal in color when the terminal supports colors, print it plain otherwise. Also, I'd like no color when the program is not run interactively, e.g. when piped into grep.

What's the best way to do this in Perl? I'm hoping for some API that's sort of like this:

```
printColorMaybe( RED, "Hi", PLAIN, " mom!\n" );
```

where the implementation will ignore the color codes when not appropriate.

Comment: Does this fall back to no color when I need it? From the description, it does not sound like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Term::ANSIColor`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) to produced colored output.

[`-t STDOUT`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#-X) to test whether standard output is opened to a terminal.

[`$ENV{ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964065/termansicolor-when-term-doesnt-support-colors) to dynamically disable `Term::ANSIColor`.

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
$ENV{ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED}++ unless -t STDOUT;
print colored("Hi","red")," mom!\n";
```

Comment: I'd add to this excellent answer: determining if the session is interactive can be tricky. ExtUtils::MakeMaker contains a [more comprehensive test](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.34/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm#L204) for its prompt() function, and [IO::Interactive](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Interactive) contains an even better set of heuristics.